Whisper for 100 users concurrently using websockets
import asyncio
import websockets
import numpy as np
import whisper
import torch
import threading
import time
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

# Load Whisper model instances globally
model_pool = [whisper.load_model("tiny.en") for _ in range(5)]
print('5 instances of whisper model tiny.en loaded')

# Global variables and locks
frames_locks = [threading.Lock() for _ in range(len(model_pool))]  # one lock per model instance
threshold = 20  # voice pitch threshold
ms = 500  # milliseconds
connected_clients = set()
user_data = {}
model_counter = 0  # Counter to distribute requests

async def audio_data(websocket, path):
    global connected_clients
    connected_clients.add(websocket)
    query_string = path.split('?')[1]
    query_params = dict(parse_qs(query_string))
    VAD = query_params.get('vad')
    VAD = int(VAD[0]) if VAD else ms

    connection_id = id(websocket)
    user_data[connection_id] = {
        'frames_in': [],
        'silence_duration': 0,
        'last_speech_time': time.time(),
        'start': False,
        'VAD': VAD,
        'plainResponse': False
    }

    print(f'New connection: {connection_id} | Total Connected Clients: {len(connected_clients)}')

    try:
        await handle_audio_stream(websocket, connection_id)
    finally:
        connected_clients.remove(websocket)
        del user_data[connection_id]
        print(f'Removed connection: {connection_id} | Total Connected Clients: {len(connected_clients)}')

async def handle_audio_stream(websocket, connection_id):
    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            user = user_data.get(connection_id)
            if not user:
                return
            audio_buffer = np.frombuffer(message, dtype=np.int16)
            b = ((np.abs(np.fft.rfft(audio_buffer))) * 16000 / len(message) // 2).mean()

            if b > threshold * 1000:
                user['silence_duration'] = 0
                user['start'] = True
                user['last_speech_time'] = time.time()
                user['frames_in'].append(audio_buffer)
            else:
                if user['start']:
                    user['frames_in'].append(audio_buffer)
                user['silence_duration'] = time.time() - user['last_speech_time']

            if user['silence_duration'] * 1000 >= user['VAD'] and user['start']:
                user['start'] = False
                if user['frames_in']:
                    frames_copy = user['frames_in'].copy()
                    user['frames_in'].clear()
                    audio_data_np = np.concatenate(frames_copy).astype(np.float32) / 32768.0
                    audio_tensor = torch.from_numpy(audio_data_np)

                    # Transcribe concurrently using multiple locks
                    asyncio.create_task(process_transcription(audio_tensor, websocket, connection_id))
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError:
        print(f'Connection {connection_id} closed unexpectedly.')

async def process_transcription(audio_tensor, websocket, connection_id):
    global model_counter
    lock_index = model_counter % len(frames_locks)
    model_instance = model_pool[model_counter % len(model_pool)]
    model_counter += 1

    start_time = time.time()
    with frames_locks[lock_index]:
        result = await asyncio.to_thread(model_instance.transcribe, audio_tensor)
    transcription = result['text']
    end_time = time.time()
    elapsed = end_time - start_time

    print(f"Sockets Connected: {len(connected_clients)} | Time: {elapsed} | {len(audio_tensor)}| {connection_id} --> {transcription}")

    try:
        await websocket.send(transcription)
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK:
        print(f'Connection {connection_id} closed gracefully.')

start_server = websockets.serve(audio_data, "localhost", 8001)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

i tried asyncio and threads but failed . Can someone guide me to proper usage of threads and aysyncio to achieve concurrency for 100 users . I am using 2 RTX 3090 gpus but not achieving this .
It takes very long time to transcribe when is use threads , then i make 5 model instances and do trancribing for 100 users with 5 models but failed
